# content-security-policy meta tag for allowing web socket

Tags: cordova, websocket, socket.io, phonegap-plugins, content-security-policy

Situation: autoreload of `phonegap serve` blocked by content-security-policy meta tag

Adding content security policy prevents auto-reload of `phonegap serve` utility. This is built on top of `cordova serve` but auto-reloads the app on file editing. It works by injecting `socket.io` in `index.html`. What should I specify in my CSP meta tag that will allow socket connections to my laptop.

Here is my current CSP meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 192.168.0.100 * ws:* ; connect-src ws://192.168.0.100 ws:*">
```

However on opening, the device keeps showing "Connecting to device" and not event is received on the device.

Also note that it starts working on removing this meta tag which mean the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` might not be blocking it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To add web sockets to the security policy you add the web socket protocol (ws:) to the connect-src directive.

```
connect-src 'self' ws:;
```

Optionally, you can add the ws: protocol to the default-src and omit connect-src. Here is a useful example that enables most local development needs while still providing useful security constraints.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ws: ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline';">
```

The documentation for [content security policy](https://content-security-policy.com/) is surprisingly good and easy to read.

Comment: this helped only addition is is I need to add wss: for secure web socket

Comment: Great! How to limit to ws://localhost? I'm trying but it's not working.

Comment: Works by just adding the default-src 'self' ws:    When adding the connect-src policy, you also need to include the domains for other APIs and widgets. Otherwise, you will get content blocked errors.

Answer (score 5):

If your websocket is on the same host/port then both `connect-src 'self'` or `default-src 'self'` *SHOULD* be sufficient - presuming that [browsers have implemented the changes](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/5052) since the CSP spec changes in https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/7 ([PR](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/commit/0e81d81b64c42ca3c81c048161162b9697ff7b60)).

Comment: Right now safari does not support a websocket to self wih 'self'

Answer (score -7):

I had a a similar issue. This effects Cordova 5.x.x. See this blog post by Nic Raboy https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/05/whitelist-external-resources-for-use-in-ionic-framework/

I had to tweak the meta tag a bit to get my websocket to connect as well. Here is what that looks like;

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Comment: That worked. I guess I was missing `script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'`

Comment: This answer is misleading and on the dangerous side. The * enables connections from all sources which defeats the security policy. See the other answer for more details.