# Contenct Security Policy refuses connect to Websocket Error

Tags: iis, websocket, content-security-policy

i can't connect to the websocket because of my CSP (Content Security Policy) - what is wrong?

Error:

> ps-client-component-websocket-adapter.js:412 Refused to connect to
>   'wss://hostname.domain:port/jsonWebSocket' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'".

My IIS web.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <configuration>
            <system.webServer>
                <httpProtocol>
                    <customHeaders>
                        <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />   
                        <!---<add name="X-Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; child-src *;" />-->
                        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="connect-src 'self' wss://hostname.domain:port/jsonWebSocket; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data:; object-src 'none'; child-src *;" />              
                    </customHeaders>
                </httpProtocol>
            </system.webServer>
        </configuration>
        </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but [as per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src),

> connect-src 'self' does not resolve to websocket schemas in all browsers, more info in [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/7).

You may want to add `wss` to `connect-src` as it is done [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41389590/4926545) for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing comma in `connect-src`.

Comment: Could you clarify? Could you send the updated version?